# How to solve the error upgrading pip on Mac OS?

Tags: python, pip

```
taimourabdulkarim@Taimours-MacBook-Air ~ % pip3 install --upgrade pip
zsh: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3: bad interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.9: no such file or directory
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/02/9ab8b431aca1b46fcc1ac830a5870a28a12ba1abfa681904b1d2da876a86/pip-21.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'RECORD'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
taimourabdulkarim@Taimours-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Comment: Your question is unformatted, so it makes it very difficult to follow, as you have not put any additional description. Provided you have the necessarily permissions to modify files in the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/site-packages` directory, I would recommend using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` where you need to explicitly specify Python's path.

Comment: Avoid running plain ``pip``/``pip3`` – *especially* when you get a warning that the native interpreter for the program is missing! Use ``python -m pip`` or ``python3 -m pip`` or even the *full* path to the desired interpreter.